# Use api in Jhipster from Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, spring-mvc, syntax-error, jhipster

I have a problem when using Jhipster. I have two project: Project1 is runing in `localhost:8080` and Project2 is running in `localhost:8081`. 
In Project2 I have api: `localhost:8081/api/posts/new`

this is code in server:

```
/**
 * GET /posts/new : get new the posts.
 *
 * @param pageable
 *            the pagination information
 * @return the ResponseEntity with status 200 (OK) and the list of posts in
 *         body
 * @throws URISyntaxException
 *             if there is an error to generate the pagination HTTP headers
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/posts/new", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<List<PostLessDTO>> getNewPosts(Pageable pageable) throws URISyntaxException {
    log.debug("REST request to get a page of Posts");
    Page<Post> page = postRepository.findAllByStatusOrderByCreatedDateDesc(pageable, Status.APPROVED);
    HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(page, "/api/posts/new");
    return new ResponseEntity<>(postMapper.postsToPostLessDTOs(page.getContent()), headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I want use this api in my Project1 so I code in Project1 (Angular)
First I write a Service Utilities

```
(function() {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('giasanApp')
    .factory('Utilities', Utilities);

Utilities.$inject = ['$resource'];

function Utilities($resource) {

    return $resource('http://localhost:8081/api/posts/new', {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true
        }
    });

}
})();
```

Then I use service in Controller:

```
Utilities.get(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

But it not working !!
This is result in firefox Browser:

[this is response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XleeF.png)

Comment: Thank for your answer. But the response actually JSON, I has checked it in my browser. I don't understand about API protected, Could you tell me more about this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Are there errors in your console about doing a cross-domain request?